# Is it recommended to change targetSdkVersion in app?

Tags: android, sdk, version, target

I have an app in the market that is targeting Android SDK 23 at the moment.

My problem is that with the release of Android 6, users have to accept dangerous permissions at runtime. I have got my first crash regarding this and I want to solve it fast before it gets serious.

I want to do it correctly as Android recommend asking the user at runtime to accept the permission and if not, hide the feature and stuff. But that takes time and will be done in the future. :)

But, would be for now changing the targetSdkVersion to 22 be a valid solution? What would that mean for users with Android 6 that have already installed the app?

I hope my quiestion is clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> If an app targets the Marshmallow SDK, it means that the app is aware of the new features and can use them

I think that if you're not handling the permissions as Android 6 is supposed target it one API lower because this is the compatibility of you're app

Btw it is recommended to ask the critical permissions on the start of the app and the minor when needed.
Hope that I helped.